# Degraded Stack Exchange network performance

Tags: bug, status-completed, performance

Subject should say it all, but overall the Stack Exchange network has been very laggy (so far) all day on, February 27th and 28th.

I am connecting from Brooklyn, NY, USA is happening on my home ISP connection (Spectrum) as well as my cell service provider (T-Mobile). I am not using a VPN of any kind; direct connection to the provider in both cases.

Everything from loading modals to page loads and this becomes very apparent when reviewing items in the “Review” queue: Instead of quickly moving from item to item, utterly every action seems to lag. Even saving edits results in a lag.

What’s happening?

Comment: I've noticed that too: 30 seconds to register a spam flag, etc

Comment: I'm seeing an uptick in AI generated answers being posted all over the network. I wonder if it's related.

Comment: @ColleenV Maybe it's not an increase of answers but lack of flags taking them down due to flags being slow as molasses.

Comment: I thought that was only on my side :) In any case: I feel like it's gotten worse today.

Comment: I experienced that bad performance on Math SE and on Meta SE today, but right now it seems to be good again.

Comment: All better as of about 9:00 CST in Minnesota.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**[UPDATE #7 (March 11)]** Issue has been resolved. The team has adjusted the way traffic is distributed among various load balancers and the fixes appear to have been holding solid for a number of days now. Thanks again for the patience while the team worked on this.

**[UPDATE #6]** The team feels they're getting closer to discovering the cause, but the current investigation has made clear this may take some time. I'll post an update next Monday to keep folks in the loop if I don't have something to report before then.

**[UPDATE #5]** Just an fyi that the team is still working on this - no expected further updates until Monday. Thanks for the patience folks!

**[UPDATE #4]** Team is still tracking down the root cause of the issue. Site speed is still intermittent in the meantime. I'll update this again when I have more information.

**[UPDATE #3]** Team believe they have found the problem spot (a particular load balancer pair), so the site should be working at normal speeds again. They're still investigating the root cause, so I'll leave the status-review tag up until that has been determined and resolved. Thanks for the patience (and the updates when the site has gone south again).

**[UPDATE #2]** Team is aware yesterday's actions did not fix the issue and are currently investigating the site sluggishness. I'll keep you posted.

**[UPDATE #1]** The team has gotten the site stabilized, but is still investigating the root cause. I'm leaving this with the status-reviewed tag for now until we know what actually caused the issue. Thanks for the patience in the meantime, folks.

Team is aware and working on it. Thanks for the report. I'll share more info once I have it (and I'll update this answer once the issue has been resolved).

Comment: It is *still* lagging, almost unuseable. Review queues are as slow as a snail.

Comment: Weird... Maybe an ongoing result of this issue, but I clicked an HNQ link to get back to [diy.se] from [workplace.se], and got a "this site is in read only mode" banner and I wasn't logged in. I hit back on the browser, then clicked the burger menu & selected [diy.se]. Got the site up, no banner and I was logged in as expected. This happened a few minutes ago.

Comment: @FreeMan [I just got the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QouF.png). I opened ~20 links at just about the same time. Only one of them had this message.

Comment: Few other things I got since: [error when trying to flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OzsK.png), [error when opening the inline tag editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtuZA.png), [error when trying to save an inline tag edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9ctz.png). Waiting a bit and repeating the action went around each.

Comment: Note that there's a new post of [“SE Network intermittent availability” on February 29th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398144/562482) regarding the same type of problem occurring again today.

Comment: Time to come clean, it's taking so long so that you can gain more reputation! :D

Comment: Ha! Definitely not.