# “SE Network intermittent availability” on February 29th

Tags: bug

Seems like there are intermittent issues across the Stack Exchange network as of February 29, 2024.

I am connecting from Brooklyn, NY, USA is happening on my home ISP connection (Spectrum) as well as my cell service provider (T-Mobile). I am not using a VPN of any kind; direct connection to the provider in both cases.

Just got a “read only” banner while on Super User; quickly cleared up on page reload. See attached pic:

[image]

And the [Stack Status page](https://www.stackstatus.net) reflects this as well.

[image]

Comment: I've also been encountering this problem on several occasions today as well. Doing a refresh has always solved it previously but, just around when you were posting your question, even refreshing twice on a Stack Overflow question did not work. Nonetheless, going back to it a bit later, refreshing then worked properly. Note that, although the answer by Dalmarus states it's now been fixed, this appears to be a reiteration of what [Degraded Stack Exchange network performance on February 27th and (yet still) on February 28th?](/q/398067) discusses.